# Laravel/PHP Echo in form text issue

Tags: php, laravel

I have a piece of code in Laravel 4.2.

```
 {{ Form::label('field2', 'Your RCID') }}
 {{ Form::text('field2', '{{$auth_id}}' , array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

When I run it on my web browser I'm getting an error,

```
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';'



<?php echo Form::label('field2', 'Your RCID'); ?>
<?php echo Form::text('field2', '{{$auth_id; ?>' , array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

What could I be doing wrong with it? When I DBug or I run a php echo it shows up just fine. Basically I want to populate a text field in a form. Any insights would be greatly appreciated here. (New to Laravel)

Comment: brackets are like <?php ?> you have brackets inside brackets and that does not make sense, raghave answer is correct

Comment: ok gotcha, thanks for the help, like I said Im new to laravel here, come from C# and .VB lol

Comment: good luck with php :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change to

```
{{ Form::text('field2', $auth_id, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Comment: ah - so I dont need the '' or the {{ }} then.